# Using Ionic with Smart Card (Java Card)

Tags: java, javascript, cordova, smartcard, ionic-framework

Good day,

I have a project on building mobile app that read and write data to a smart card (java card),
in form of text as a storage using a USB connector to an android mobile phone to communicate with the card.

But i know Ionic (cordova/ Javascript) does not have a plugin to read/write with smart card
My research show that it can only be done with java, But i do not want to design the app from ground up 
using a native language cos i have loved working with ionic - cordova.

i need a help on ways to make this work, i dont want to believe that it is not possible, 
i need a resources, technic, materials that i can use to make this possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a preexisting solution then you would have to plugin your own for the platforms you require. There seems to be an [NFC plugin](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.chariotsolutions.nfc.plugin) which can form a starting point on how to build such a thing.

You could use the [seek-for-Android](https://code.google.com/p/seek-for-android/wiki/SmartcardAPI) project as base to build your own API. In the simplest form you could just decide to make a port: basically copying the API into Cordoba.

Note that all this may not be easy. Good luck.